# Remove cell editing style in read-only Silverlight DataGrids

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid in Silverlight in ReadOnly mode.  However, the DataGrid still allows selecting individual cells (changes background color and adds a thin blue border).  I believe, the DataGrid is still turning the cell into a TextBox, but making it read-only.

I don't want the user to be able to select a single-cell, only a row.  Is there anyway to accomplish this using the default Silverlight DataGrid?

Thanks,
  Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/hilighting-entire-rows-in-datagrid/

There are a couple of solutions that i've seen, they all basically edit the style to prevent it from showing up like that.